# Google Apps Script - Combining events from two calendars?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have tried a lot of things to combine 2 calendars and none of them seem to work. On their own things work great. I would love them to stay in order by date when joined if possible.

This works great on it's own.

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
var events = cal.getEvents(new Date(StartDate), new Date(EndDate), {search: ""});
...
var details=[[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getStartTime(), events[i].getEndTime(), events[i].getDateCreated(), events[i].getLastUpdated()]];
```

None of my attempts are working

```
var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
var cal2 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(bCal);

var temp = cal.getEvents(new Date(StartDate), new Date(EndDate));
var temp2 = cal2.getEvents(new Date(StartDate), new Date(EndDate));

//Failed attempts

var events = temp + temp2;
 //or

var events = temp.join(temp2);

//or

var events = temp & temp2;
```

Please piont me in the correct direction.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I would love them to stay in order by date when joined if possible.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getCalEvents() {
  var cal1 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(mycal);
  var cal2 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(bCal);
  var arr1 = cal1.getEvents(new Date(StartDate), new Date(EndDate));
  var arr1 = cal2.getEvents(new Date(StartDate), new Date(EndDate));
  var arr3 = arr1.concat(arr2);
  arr3.sort((a, b) => {return a.getStartTime().valueOf() - b.getStartTime().valueOf()});
}
```

Comment: I had to change 
`arr3.sort((a, b) => {return a.startTime().valueOf() - b.startTime().valueOf()});`
to `var events = arr3.sort((a, b) => {return a.getStartTime().valueOf() - b.getStartTime().valueOf()});
everything else worked! Thank you, Cooper!